# Multiple forms views in code igniter

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have a Controller named `Author`. Inside the controller, I have defined a submit function that takes care of the 3-step form process. Right now I have only created the first form.

```
class Author extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
    }

    public function submit() {  
        $this->load->view('author/submit_step1');
    }

}
```

The form1 that is loaded in the view points to the URL (action)

```
http://localhost/zabjournal/Author/submit/2
```

My objective is to save the values of the first form to a database, and then load the 2nd form.

Given the action of the form, How should I design the controller so that I can access a model and save the details of the first form, and then load the view for the 2nd form.

Comment: You need to register a form model in the session that stores each step-form-values. As you want to save that model into the DB as well, do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public function submit (){

if ($this->input->post('submit-1')) //Use unique names for each submit button value on the forms
{
    //validate and save form data to database

    $this->load->view('author/submit_step2');
}
elseif ($this->input->post('submit-2'))
{
    //validate and save form data to database

    $this->load->view ('author/submit_step3');
}
elseif ($this->input->post('submit-3'))
{
    //validate and save form data to database

    $this->load->view('author/success');
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('author/submit_step1');
}

}
```

Comment: To make it more compatible with the URL supplied in the question, submit() should expect a variable, $step for example, that you you use in the if statement, rather than the post variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the redirect function to the controller that loads the second form.
For example

```
//the function that loads the first form<br><br>
public function load_firstForm() {  
        $this->load->view('author/form1');
    }

//in your form1 use form_open('author/submit_step1') to access the second function

public function submit_step1() {
        //load your model here and a method to save these items

      //redirect to the same controller but the second method that loads the second form
       redirect('author/submit_step2');
    }

//function that loads form2

public function submit_step2() {  
        $this->load->view('author/form2');//loads the second form
    }
```

etc. Hope this helps.